# Telegram Bot Poll payload without chat data

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, python-telegram-bot

When receiving plain messages (`MessageHandler`) or callback queries (`CallbackQueryHandler`) the update payload includes the chat object (id, type, etc..)

```
{'update_id': 696992165, 
    'message': {'message_id': 1267, 'date': 1589968391, 
       'chat': {'id': 931365322, 'type': 'private',
```

In case of Poll (`PollHandler`) this is not the case (only the question, answers, and info related to the poll question)

```
{'update_id': 696992167, 
  'poll': {'id': '5920521737891479577', 'question': 'What is the capital of Ukraine?', 
   'options': [{'text': 'Rabat', 'voter_count': 0}, 
               {'text': 'Kyiv', 'voter_count': 1}, 
               {'text': 'Luxembourg', 'voter_count': 0}], 
       'total_voter_count': 1, 'is_closed': False, 'is_anonymous': True, 
     'type': 'quiz', 'allows_multiple_answers': False, 'correct_option_id': 1, 
     'explanation_entities': [], 'close_date': None}}
```

Is there a way to include the chat_data which the Poll belongs to?

Comment: Did you checked the [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.pollhandler.html#telegram.ext.PollHandler.pass_chat_data)? There seems to be a `pass_chat_data` parameter for the `PollHandler`!

Comment: Tried that and no difference (btw it is deprecated)

Comment: what kind of information do you need from chat_data, everything?

Comment: chat_id  ideally so I know which chat the answer belongs too. I look more into Telegram doc (not the Python module) and it looks like the returned object does not contain anything else, I am not sure there is a way to get the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the bot creates a poll (using Polling, I can't speak about webhooks yet) it updates its `bot_data` with `{poll_id: {'chat_id': chat_id, 'message_id': message_id}}` and when your bot process an answer, you can get the `poll_id` from `update.poll.id` and then use it on `context.bot_data` to get the `chat_id`

```
def poll_answer_handler(update, context):
    chatId = context.bot_data[update.poll.id]['chat_id']
```

It's important to **do not stop/restart the bot** at any point between the creation of the poll and requesting the `chat_id`, otherwise the `bot_data` will be empty. Solution? Having *persistence* makes the `bot_data` persistent.

PS: This goes for Python-Telegram-Bot 12.6